# Macro run only on visible cells

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I was wondering how do I make macro run only on visible(unhidden) cells?
 what should I add to this code:?

```
Dim cell As Range 

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
    With Application.FindFormat.Interior 
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic 
        .Color = 16711935 
        .TintAndShade = 0 
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0 
    End With 
    Cells.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _ 
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _ 
    , SearchFormat:=True).Activate 
Next cell 
Exit Sub
```

Comment: How is your code working now?  How is it dysfunctional?

Comment: dysfunction is that current code searches through the whole sheet , even if searched value is in hidden row - it finds it (it shouldn't be finding it)

Comment: OK, but I see you have an accepted answer, so I won't comment further.

Comment: I have. Still thanks for good intentions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Activate all visible the cells with a specific format.

```
Sub Example()

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim c As Range, FoundRange As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    On Error Resume Next

    Set SearchRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not SearchRange Is Nothing Then

        With Application.FindFormat.Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 16711935
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

        Set c = SearchRange.Find(What:="", After:=SearchRange.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
                                 xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
              , SearchFormat:=True)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Set FoundRange = c
            Do
                Set c = SearchRange.Find(What:="", After:=c, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
                                         xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
                      , SearchFormat:=True)

                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    'Do Something

                    Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, c)
                End If
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress

            FoundRange.Activate
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, but macro doesn't have to do anything with found cells. It just has to find them and select :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's not checking formulas, you can change

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

or if it's checking formulas, change

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
```

This will keep it from running on blank cells that aren't hidden.

Comment: I guess it doesn't check formulas , as my only interest is cell color :) Thanks for your help btw :) - Alex , Thomas Inzina